# How to Fetch data from 3GB json file and insert into DB CI 3

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I'd created a function to store data fetched by Json file into DB Table

```
public function work_with_json()
{
    $file = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/Projects/FoodData.json';
    $jsonData = file_get_contents($file);
    $data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

    if ($data === null) {
        echo "Error parsing JSON data.";
        return;
    }

    $surveyFoods = $data['SurveyFoods'];
    $chunkSize = 100;
    $counter = 0;

    $chunkedData = array_chunk($surveyFoods, $chunkSize);

    foreach ($chunkedData as $chunk) {
        $this->insertDataIntoDB($chunk);
        $counter += count($chunk);
    }

    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '<br/>';
    echo $counter . ' data inserted successfully.';
}
```

And insertDataIntoDB Function is

```
public function insertDataIntoDB($chunkData)
{
    $dataArray = [];
    foreach ($chunkData as $jsonObject) {
        $dataArray[] = $jsonObject;
    }
    p($dataArray); die;
}
```

And The Data In The JSON File is In This Format This is Small Part of that data:-

```
{
"SurveyFoods": [
    {
        "foodClass": "Survey",
        "description": "Milk, human",
        "foodNutrients": [
            {
                "type": "FoodNutrient",
                "id": 28540524,
                "nutrient": {
                    "id": 1003,
                    "number": "203",
                    "name": "Protein",
                    "rank": 600,
                    "unitName": "g"
                },
                "amount": 1.03
            }
        ],
        "foodAttributes": [
            {
                "id": 2641190,
                "name": "WWEIA Category number",
                "value": "9602",
                "foodAttributeType": {
                    "id": 999,
                    "name": "Attribute",
                    "description": "Generic attributes"
                }
            }
        ],
        "foodCode": "11000000",
        "startDate": "1/1/2019",
        "endDate": "12/31/2020",
        "wweiaFoodCategory": {
            "wweiaFoodCategoryCode": 2641191,
            "wweiaFoodCategoryDescription": "Human milk"
        },
        "foodPortions": [
            {
                "id": 267798,
                "measureUnit": {
                    "id": 9999,
                    "name": "undetermined",
                    "abbreviation": "undetermined"
                },
                "modifier": "30000",
                "gramWeight": 30.800000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125,
                "sequenceNumber": 3,
                "portionDescription": "1 fl oz"
            }
        ],
        "publicationDate": "10/28/2022",
        "inputFoods": [
            {
                "id": 104096,
                "unit": "GM",
                "portionDescription": "NONE",
                "portionCode": "0",
                "foodDescription": "Milk, human, mature, fluid (For Reference Only)",
                "sequenceNumber": 1,
                "ingredientDescription": "Milk, human, mature, fluid (For Reference Only)",
                "ingredientWeight": 100,
                "amount": 100,
                "ingredientCode": 1107
            }
        ],
        "fdcId": 2340760,
        "dataType": "Survey (FNDDS)"
    }
]
```

}

After Running this function system gets hang for that 3GB Json File but it's Working for smaller Json File.
Any Help would be appreciated.